# How to I add a hyperlink to a cell in axlsx?

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet, axlsx

With the `spreadsheet` gem, you can run `Spreadsheet::Link.new('http://hyperlinkhere.com', 'Some words')` to make a spreadsheet with a cell containing the string "Some words" with a hyperlink leading to "http://hyperlinkhere.com."

What's the `axlsx` equivalent?

EDIT: What if I want to write a row with more than one cell?

With `spreadsheet`, you can do this:

```
        newSheetRow[13] = Spreadsheet::Link.new('url.com','text')
        newSheetRow[14] = 'some text'
```

How do I do that with `axlsx`'s `.add_row` method?

Comment: My case is a bit different, but since this answers is well linked already: I wanted to add a hyperlink to only a portion of text within a cell, but after manual testing in Excel, found that is not possible: https://superuser.com/questions/428299/hyperlinking-a-piece-of-text-in-excel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add both links within workbook and URLs.

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new
book = p.workbook
book.add_worksheet(:name => 'hyperlinks') do |sheet|
  # external references
  sheet.add_row ['axlsx']
  sheet.add_hyperlink :location => 'https://github.com/randym/axlsx', :ref => sheet.rows.first.cells.first
  # internal references
  sheet.add_hyperlink :location => "'Next Sheet'!A1", :ref => 'A2', :target => :sheet
  sheet.add_row ['next sheet']
end
```

Comment: if i add integer is it not working 'sheet.add_row ['123']'